# Using node-mysql in a function

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm very new to nodejs and have a question.

Trying to create a function that will call the value of any field where I mention its ID from a table:

```
function getUserInfo (userID, dynamicField) {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT '+dynamicField+' from users WHERE userID = '+connection.escape(userID));
    query.on('result', function(row) {
        return(row.dynamicField);
    });
};
console.log(getUserInfo(8, userEmail)) //this should get me the userEmail value of the user with userID=8
```

However, I get "undefined". If I use console.log rather than return, it logs the value but this has no use as a function to be used inside other functions to get a value.

I will be glad if I can get help for modifying the function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common mistake amongst async/nodejs beginners. You have essentially wrapped an async function inside a sync function which breaks down the nature of node's event loop. The return expression needs to be replaced with a callback. See below:

```
// Method
function getUserInfo (userID, dynamicField, callback) {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT '+dynamicField+' from users WHERE userID = '+connection.escape(userID));
    query.on('result', function(row) {
        callback(null, row.dynamicField);
    });
};

// Implementation
getUserInfo(8, userEmail, function(err, result){
    console.log(err || result);
});
```

By convention, in Nodejs we always pass an error object first in the callback. In this case since there is no error to capture, we pass null in its place.

Comment: Yes, not-thinking the PHP (sync) way seems to take time. Thanks so much.

Comment: although I have marked it as the "accepted answer", after trying the code, I'm still getting "undefined".

I just changed this line to
getUserInfo(8, userEmail, function(err, result){
to
getUserInfo(8, 'userEmail', function(err, result){

but no luck..

Comment: I just missed something simple (the brackets):

callback(null, row[dynamicField];

Comment: Took a while for me too (I came from PHP as well). So you figured it out?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. 

Actually, it works without adding the callback function as (that's why I think) query.on('result' is already a callback.

I tried many things and realized that I have to think everything asyn, not only functions and shape all the code in that way.. :)

Thanks much again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was having a lot of difficulties working with functions within NODE, I also come from PHP, but I've been working with VUE for some time, but with NODE I'm catching on small traps that for a beginner is very difficult to discover.